# (Heterogeneous) Chargepump questions

Tags: capacitor, voltage-doubler

**Updated** to have organized schematic below, as was suggested. Keeping the original in case of..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwgY2h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to build a chargepump, where I want to use the second capacitor with doubled voltage as the power supply, detached from Vin.

The first capacitor will have a small capacity, the second will be larger.

[image]

Above is my current sketch (forgive me for the shoddy quality, it used to be worse..). I have added two diodes and two transistors. The transistors fire alternating. The capacitors charge, but where the first one is 3v (Vin is 3.3) and the second is a little below that, but not 6v as I would assume.

I have not added a way yet to drain the second capacitor.

I have also tried with optocoupler and was also unsuccessful, but that may be due to other reasons..

I was succesful building the chargepump with an Arduino found here: https://sites.google.com/site/wayneholder/12-volt-charge-pump
However I'm looking to use a 12V or higher Vin with high current.

Comment: where are the transistors? You can use the schematic editor on this site when you edit your question, it's the resistor/capacitor/diode/pencil button, well worth using, it means your question is more likely to be taken seriously. Remeber, ground to the bottom, +ve to the top, 'flow' left to right.

Comment: I have updated the post using the schematic editor, thank you for the suggestion, makes it a lot easier.

Comment: That circuit won't work at all. You'll need a lot more transistors, because you want to alternately connect the capacitors in parallel to charge them, and then connect them in series to discharge them into the load at twice the voltage.

Comment: @DaveTweed So if I charge two capacitors in parallel and put them in series, what will the capacity be when both are depleted this way? Also is this best done with capacitors of the same size?

Comment: I don't see any questions here...

Comment: @immibis "the second is a little below that, but not 6v as I would assume."

Comment: @DariusJoe And? That isn't a question.

Comment: @immibis You have a good eye for things, I'll be damned!

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of a flying-capacitor charge pump looks more like this, shown with switches instead of transistors and diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBqVbl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I've seen that circuit, however I'm unsure how to build it with transistors (or mosfets). I've seen someone recommend mosfet SSR's (which I don't have ATM), but they seem slow. Relays are mostly slow and energy consuming too as far as I know.